# CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled turn on but individual is turned off

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I need know when gps is not working. With switcher for all app its correctly, locationServicesEnabled = YES or NO, but if I turn ON location for app and turn OFF for my app, locationServicesEnabled YES, but gps is not available. 
And also not show message in this case "Turn On Location Services to Allow "MyApp" to determine Your Location".

How I can determine what location for my app is off?

Comment: This is already answered question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825118/how-to-detect-if-user-did-not-allow-location-update/9825147#9825147

Answer (score 1):

I expect you are looking for

```
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]
```

It returns one of these

```
kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized,
kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways = kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized,
kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse
```

Which is a status report per *App*, not per *Device*

*update*
fixed location manager class name as per Denis' comment

Comment: Thanks. Its help me find solution. Most like what CoreLocationManager is deprecated. I use CLLLocationManager and also found example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377069/kclauthorizationstatusnotdetermined-occurred-when-tested-with-ios-6-1-simulator

Comment: @DenisS - sorry, I was going from memory. CLLocationManager is correct, i've fixed the answer. I am using it in a test app for beacons [here](http://www.github.com/foundry/ibeacons) - see `+(void) logAvailability` in the [MBCLHelpers class](https://github.com/foundry/ibeacons/blob/master/MyBeacon/MBCLHelpers.m)